# CoffeeScript, looking for SQL-like Module

Tags: sql, sqlite, node.js, coffeescript

I'm attempting to make CoffeeScript allow SQL statements along with it's normal grammar. This requires a decent SQLite/MySQL/SimilarDB module to add to CoffeeScript to allow the changes I'm making to the grammar. Anyone know of any good modules for doing what I need?

I've googled the hell out of this and found the following (broken) solutions:

https://github.com/orlandov/node-sqlite

https://github.com/grumdrig/node-sqlite

http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/databases/sqlite

If you do comment, please be sure the module you're referring to WORKS. There are a lot of old modules that no longer work with the most recent NodeJS release. The following github project is the project I forked from and am attempting to modify.

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking for a way to embed SQL into a coffee file? For example, by creating a custom lexer?

Comment: @Joel: Yes. It's actually a project I'm working on. I'd like to be able to add SQL statements natively within CoffeeScript. And yes, it involves manipulating the lexer/grammar files to accept/parse the SQL statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After endless google searches for some useful information, ran across some in-progress SQL module projects for CoffeeScript listed below.

https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3
Contains working SQLite support.

https://github.com/sdepold/sequelize
Contains working SQLite and MySQL support. Only works with the following versions of NodeJS: 0.4.12, 0.5.10, 0.6.6.

https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-persist
Contains working SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and Oracle support.